# Making a list of variables

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, variable-definitions, variable, interface

Consider the following code, which give a `Manipulate` object that returns the "total" of a certain variable `var 1`

```
Manipulate[Total@x, Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Number", 
     Slider[Dynamic@nv, {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]},
    {"var 1", Slider[Dynamic@x, {0, 100, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]}
    }], ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Now, imagine I want to define a list of variables `var 1`, `var 2`, ..., `var 10` that depends on my choice for the first slider `nv` (number of variables), upon which I want to define a function (say `Total`, for example). I naively tried the following

```
Manipulate[Total@xl,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Number", 
     Slider[Dynamic@nv, {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]},
    Sequence @@
     Table[{StringForm["var ``", j], 
       Slider[Dynamic@(xl[[j]]), {0, 100, 1}, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"]}, {j, nv}]
    }], ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

which dynamically updates the number of sliders, but returns the following error

[image]

It seems the variable list `xl` enters in conflict with `Dynamic`, but I think there's more to it that I don't understand. I also tried playing around with `Symbol` and creating something like `Table[Symbol["$x" <> ToString@i], {i, 10}]` to use as my variable list, but with no success. Indexed variables got me a bit closer, also by excluding `j` from `Dynamic`, but still not working:

```
Manipulate[Sum[xl[j], {j, nv}],
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Number", 
     Slider[Dynamic@nv, {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]},
    Sequence @@
     Table[{StringForm["var ``", j], 
       Slider[Dynamic[xl][j], {0, 100, 1}, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"]}, {j, nv}]
    }], ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we have here is a logical situation in which an inner UI is to be generated by the value of an outer variable. So I would prefer to build the inner and outer components separately.

```
ClearAll[constructInnerUI, constructOuterUI];
constructInnerUI[nv_Integer] := nv // RightComposition[
    Range,
    Map[
        ToString /* OperatorApplied[StringJoin, 2]["x"] /* Symbol /*
        List /* Append[Range @ 100]
    ],
    Through @* {OperatorApplied[Part, {3, 1, 2}][All, 1] /* Total, Splice},
    OperatorApplied[Join][{Paneled -> False, FrameMargins -> None}],
    Apply[Manipulate]
];

constructOuterUI[] := Manipulate[
    constructInnerUI[nv],
    {nv, Range @ 100},
    Paneled -> False, FrameMargins -> None
];

constructOuterUI[]
```

Hopefully this will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I found that using `With` might help. I just need to manually set the initial values for `xl`

```
Do[xl[j] = 1, {j, 10}];
Manipulate[Sum[xl[j], {j, nv}], Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Number", 
     Slider[Dynamic@nv, {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]},
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[With[{j = j}, {StringForm["var ``", j], 
        Slider[Dynamic[xl[j]], {0, 100, 1}, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"]}], {j, nv}]}],
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

Please let me know if there is a better or alternative way of doing this.